# how to rebuild/reload qtFormLayout with updated list

Tags: python, qt

I have a `QFormLayout` created via Qt Designer. 
I go through a list and for each element I create a checkbox and a label.
So far everything works fine.

What I can't figure out is how to actually reload/rebuild all the checkboxes with a new list. Basically throwing away the old checkboxes from the list and create new ones based on a new list.

what I have so far:

```
    for i in singlePassesSplit:
        if i != '':
            self.checkBox = PySide.QtGui.QCheckBox()
            self.ui.tSS_formLayout.addRow(self.checkBox, PySide.QtGui.QLabel('          ' + i ) )
```

Comment: solved it by changing the QFormLayout to a Qlistwidget